# Connecting to a VPN from AWS workspace (Linux)

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpn

I have just created a stock Amazon Workspace (Linux). I would like to connect to a PPTP VPN (Public, but outside of Amazon). Here are the distro details

```
NAME="Amazon Linux"
VERSION="2"
ID="amzn"
ID_LIKE="centos rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="2"
PRETTY_NAME="Amazon Linux 2"
ANSI_COLOR="0;33"
CPE_NAME="cpe:2.3:o:amazon:amazon_linux:2"
HOME_URL="https://amazonlinux.com/"
Amazon Linux 2
```

When it comes to understanding VPN I am a newbie (do not know much beyond "all the VPN traffic  is opaque on the wire". All the searches I have done come up with how to setup a VPN *server* in AWS. It does not look like the instances come with a bundelled PPTP GUI/CLI.
I have already installed `pptp` and `pptpconfig`. 
Please help if you can. Thanks!

Comment: Stop Googling with "AWS" in your keywords - it'll skew everything to the server side of things. Just Google stuff like "connect to VPN linux".

Comment: @ceejayoz, I wish I had thought of that! That actually helped.

Comment: Hooray! I'm glad that helped. 

Comment: And don't use PPTP. It's horribly insecure.